Why do the number of valleys change when load is changed?
I am operating a flyback converter with 60V DC input and 6V DC output. The load connected across the output is 500mA. My mode of operation is DCM. If I have 4 valleys in the magnetizing ringing of Vds across the primary FET, it changes to 6 valleys at 100mA load. The switching frequency is unchanged in both the cases. Why does the number of valleys increases when the load is decreased?

The duty cycle decreases to accommodate the lower load current. In DCM there is therefore a longer time not conducting thus more cycles of ringing.
